# Group presentation where relations consist of inverse elements

Tags: group-theory

Consider a group presentation $G= \langle x_{1} , x_{2} , \ldots , x_{n} \mid r_{i} (x_{1} , x_{2} , \dots , x_{n} ) \rangle$. How does the presentation $\langle x_{1} , x_{2} , \ldots , x_{n} \mid r_{i} (x_{1}^{-1} , x_{2}^{-1} , \ldots , x_{n}^{-1} ) \rangle$ relate to $G$?

Comment: Please check the $\LaTeX$ editing I did on your question.

Answer (score 1):

They present the same group, really. Just note that the group generated by $x_1, \dots, x_n$ is the same as the group generated by $x_1^{-1}, \dots, x_n^{-1}$.

So the second presentation can be rewritten as
$$
\langle x_{1} , x_{2} , \ldots , x_{n} \mid r_{i} (x_{1}^{-1} , x_{2}^{-1} , \ldots , x_{n}^{-1} ) \rangle
=
\langle x_{1}^{-1} , x_{2}^{-1} , \ldots , x_{n}^{-1} \mid r_{i} (x_{1}^{-1} , x_{2}^{-1} , \ldots , x_{n}^{-1} ) \rangle
=
\langle y_{1} , y_{2} , \ldots , y_{n} \mid r_{i} (y_{1} , y_{2} , \ldots , y_{n} ) \rangle,
$$
which is the same as the first presentation.